# React component briefly renders the wrong data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a Profile component that checks to see if the user passed in url params. If not, the Profile component will render using the current logged in user. If they did, it will pull that value and use that userid for the Profile form.

Everything renders. And the proper profiles eventually appear, however if the user passes in different userid to view, the form will first render their own Profile...THEN render the passed in user.

I'm fairly confident that it's an issue of the props not being set at the time the first render occurs. My question is how can I prevent this?

I'm using react router 4.0. I setup a parent child component trying to do a conditional render...nothing seems to help.

My parent render function looks like this:

```
{this.props.match.params.userId && (
  <ProfileForm
    key={this.props.match.params.userId}
    profileId={this.props.match.params.userId}
  />
)}
{!this.props.match.params.userId && <ProfileForm />}
```

My Route statement is this:

```
<Route exact={true} path={routes.PROFILE} component={Profile} />
<Route path={`${routes.PROFILE}/:userId`} component={Profile} />
```

Is there a way to prevent it from loading the "non-propped" version first or do I have to create a new component for "others" and have the route go there first?

Comment: How does the user "pass in" a different value? Like typing it in the url? One other point is that Route is not exact to it will match and render whether userid is available or not. Is there a repro available?

Comment: No repo is available. There's a list of link that people can click that have the user ID appended automatically. They could also type it in if they knew what it was. The default Route is set with exact.

Comment: Would you post all the routes involved? This one isn't set as exact `<Route path={`${routes.PROFILE}/:userId`} component={Profile} />`

Comment: I added the other Route for that component above. Not sure if it matters, but every other Route statement has an exact={true} property set except for a NoMatch component I have set up for 404's.

Comment: Also...I added in an exact property and tested...it made no difference. I have a feeling that the problem is related to the timing of when the properties above are being passed through. Like the router is calling the Profile component...THEN setting the match property on the props causing a refresh.